# Linq max giving inappropriate max value from table

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have a class like below from which i am trying to fetch max value for specific region :

```
public partial class Ads
    {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public int RegionId { get; set; }  
       public int Charge { get; set; } 
       public Nullable<int> Group { get; set; } 
    }
```

Records :

```
Id      RegionId    Charge   Group
1       100         100      1
```

Now i am trying to fetch max value for regionid=100 but problem is i am getting always 1 with below query :

```
int group = context.Ads.Where(a => a.RegionId == 100).Max(t => (int?)t.Group)) ?? 0 + 1;
```

Why above is giving me **1 only instead of 2** ?

Comment: why it should give 2?

Comment: @Rahul The OP expects `Max` to return 1 and then they add 1 to it.

Comment: BTW `public Nullable<int> Group { get; set; }` should be `public int? Group { get; set; }`

Comment: Check your order of precedence

Comment: @juharr you are right.thanks

Comment: Your code has too many closing parenthesis

Comment: Add parentheses around `(context... ??0) + 1`

Comment: @Rahul That class is auto generated by EF so i have that way only the way i have shown in my code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should wrap the `??` in parentheses:

```
int group = (context.Ads.Where(a => a.RegionId == 100).Max(t => (int?)t.Group) ?? 0) + 1;
```

The reason is that `??` has very low priority and if you don't use parantheses `0 + 1` at the end of code will be calculated first and it will be equal to:

```
   int group = context.Ads.Where(a => a.RegionId == 100).Max(t => (int?)t.Group) ?? 1; 
                                                                 // as 0 + 1 equals to 1
```

Comment: It might be worth adding the explanation that without this the precedence is the same as `context.Ads.Where(a => a.RegionId == 100).Max(t => (int?)t.Group)) ?? (0 + 1)` which is the same as `context.Ads.Where(a => a.RegionId == 100).Max(t => (int?)t.Group)) ?? 1`

Comment: @JonHanna I added some explanation

Comment: Still there is syntactical error  with your query i.e first query

Comment: @Learning that is because I coppied that part from your code. Please fix it in your code too.

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me so when i will not have any record this query will return 1 right instead of error that is why we have checked like this : ?? 0

Comment: @Learning yes, if `context.Ads.Where(a => a.RegionId == 100).Max(t => (int?)t.Group)` is null then `?? 0` will do its job. And Thank you

Comment: 1 last question i.e is i can also do like context.firstordefault(a=>a.regionid==100).orderbydescending(a=>a.id);Which will be more efficient from both this 2?

Comment: @Learning You can do that if the Thast record (first when order by descending) will always have the max value. otherwise you have to use the .Max

Comment: I was about too.Anyways thank you so much for the answer and please keep helping like this.Appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is it always 0, you need to put inside ()

```
int group = (context.Ads.Where(a => a.RegionId == 100).Max(t => (int?)t.Group)) ?? 0) + 1;
```

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me.Appreciated :)